# How can I get color properties of all actors?

Tags: python, pyqt5, vtk

(This might be an easy question. However I don't know the solution.)

I made an **simple multi-STL files viewer** using PyQt5 and VTK library.

There is rendering widget (`QVTKRenderWindowInteractor`) and a reset button (`QPushButton`).

If I click the reset button, the color of the actors (all loaded STL data) are changed to white.

Following code is the reset button click function
(It works well):

```
def _resetBtnClicked(self):
    # reset actor colors
    actorCollection = self.ren.GetActors()
    actorCollection.InitTraversal()

    cactor = actorCollection.GetNextActor() # first actor
    while cactor != actorCollection.GetLastActor():
        cactor.GetProperty().SetColor(1, 1, 1)
        cactor = actorCollection.GetNextActor()
    cactor.GetProperty().SetColor(1, 1, 1) # last actor
```

The self.ren is the  `vtk.vtkRenderer()` and I used while roop to deal with ACTORs COLOR using `.GetNextActor()`, sequently.

However, I want to change the while loop  to a simple code, like `self.ren.GetActors().GetProperty().SetColor(1, 1, 1)` if possible (this '`self.ren.GetActors().GetProperty().SetColor(1, 1, 1)`' isn't existed).

If there are several function I can use instead of while roop, please let me know.

Comment: don't know the datatypes - no idea what `ren`or `ren.getActor()` is/returns - but why not use a simpler `for actor in actorCollection: actor.GetProperty().SetColor(1,1,1)` ? Your question might be better served if you post a  [mcve]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The for loop works well. p.s. `ren` is `vtk.vtkRenderer()`